# Drop a column from JSON while loading through spark.read.json()

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I am stuck at a very strange situation. I have one file which has these three JSONs for example.

```
{"uploadTimeStamp":"1500618037189","ID":"123ID","data":[{"Data":{"unit":"rpm","value":"0"},"EventID":"E1","Timestamp":1500618037189,"pii":{}},{"Data":{"heading":"N","loc1":"false","loc2":"13.022425","loc3":"77.760587","loc4":"false","speed":"10"},"EventID":"E2","Timestamp":1500618037189,"pii":{}},{"Data":{"x":"1.1","y":"1.2","z":"2.2"},"EventID":"E3","Timestamp":1500618037189,"pii":{}},{"EventID":"E4","Data":{"value":"50","unit":"percentage"},"Timestamp":1500618037189},{"Data":{"unit":"kmph","value":"60"},"EventID":"E5","Timestamp":1500618037189,"pii":{}}]}
{"uploadTimeStamp":"1500618045735","ID":"123ID","data":[{"Data":{"unit":"rpm","value":"0"},"EventID":"E1","Timestamp":1500618045735,"pii":{}},{"Data":{"heading":"N","loc1":"false","loc2":"13.022425","loc3":"77.760587","loc4":"false","speed":"10"},"EventID":"E2","Timestamp":1500618045735,"pii":{}},{"Data":{"x":"1.1","y":"1.2","z":"2.2"},"EventID":"E3","Timestamp":1500618045735,"pii":{}},{"EventID":"E4","Data":{"value":"50","unit":"percentage"},"Timestamp":1500618045735},{"Data":{"unit":"kmph","value":"60"},"EventID":"E5","Timestamp":1500618045735,"pii":{}}]}
{"REGULAR_DUMMY":"REGULAR_DUMMY", "ID":"123ID", "uploadTimeStamp":1500546893837}
```

I am using spark-sql to load this json `(spark.read.json)`. I then create a temp view with `df.createOrReplaceTempView("TEST")` and the give `spark.sql("select count(*) from TEST)`

I want to get count of all records whose ID is 123ID but I want to ignore the `"REGULAR_DUMMY"` row. That means, the count(*) should come as 2 and not 3 from above case.

I have tried below approaches to drop column "REGULAR_DUMMY" to get count.

1- `val df = spark.read.json("hdfs://10.2.3.4/test/path/*).drop("REGULAR_DUMMY")` - It shows schemas as uploadTimeStamp, ID and data  which is perfectly OK. But it gives output as 3.

2 - `df.drop("REGULAR_DUMMY").createOrReplaceTempView("TEST")` - This also shows schemas as uploadTimeStamp, ID and data . But the count is 3 again

3 - `spark.sql("select count(*) from TEST).drop("REGULAR_DUMMY")` - This again gives count as 3

If I do:

`hadoop fs -cat /test/path/* | grep -i "123ID" | grep -v "REGULAR_DUMMY" | wc -l` . Then count is 2

and with:

`hadoop fs -cat /test/path/* | grep -i "123ID" | wc -l` . The count is 3

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.drop` will drop whole column and `count` will count the rows. Since you haven't deleted or filtered the rows with "REGULAR_DUMMY" value in `REGULAR_DUMMY` column, the count is 3 which is correct.

All you had to do was `filter` rows with "REGULAR_DUMMY" value in `REGULAR_DUMMY` column and do the `count` as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.filter(col("REGULAR_DUMMY") =!= "REGULAR_DUMMY").select(count("*"))
```

This is going to return you `0` as rest of the values for `REGULAR_DUMMY` column is `null`. Thus none of the rows in `REGULAR_DUMMY` column has a value, all rows are filtered out.

The solution to this would be to replace `null` values with temporary value and do `filter` and finally do the `count` as

```
df.na.fill("temp").filter(col("REGULAR_DUMMY") =!= "REGULAR_DUMMY").select(count("*"))
```

should show you the correct result as

```
+--------+
|count(1)|
+--------+
|2       |
+--------+
```

You can use `where` filter as well

```
df.na.fill("temp").where(col("REGULAR_DUMMY") =!= "REGULAR_DUMMY").select(count("*"))
```

Comment: Worked for me. Implemented the fill and filter clause before the createOrReplaceTempView. I can now query anything on the Temp View and those DUMMY columns would not appear.   Thanks!!

Comment: my pleasure @jam :) thanks for the acceptance and upvote